# Make Request With PHP And Curl Using Proxy And Allow Cookies

Tags: php, curl, cookies

My Code:

```
function skype_resolver($username) {
    $url = "http://skyperesolver.net/api/?isapi=true&get=skype&user=" . $username;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '177.12.236.216:80');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookies.txt');

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);    

    return $output;
}
```

And The Response Is:

```
Please Enable Cookies
```

How do i do?
In my browser the response of "http://skyperesolver.net/api/?isapi=true&get=skype&user=xxuser" is:

```
190.255.121.56 Country: Colombia State: Bogota D.C. City: Bogotá ISP: COLOMBIA TELECOMUNICACIONES S.A. ESP VPN Dectected: No
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do not remove your questions by editing out the content. If you post a question here, it's meant to remain after you've found a solution so that other people with the same question can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify timeout as the proxy is slow, and the request take time, and no need for any cookie.

```
function skype_resolver($username) {
    $url = "http://skyperesolver.net/api/?isapi=true&get=skype&user=" . $username;    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // If url has redirects then go to the final redirected URL.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0); //to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '177.12.236.216:80');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies.txt');


    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);    


    }
```

Comment: the same result is Please Enable Cookies, :/ is the proxy? i buyed the proxy

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the proxy port:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,             "YOUR PROXY HOST");         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT,         "YOUR PROXY PORT");
```